# Change back to old result display of nested values?

Tags: google-bigquery

Recently, BQ has changed its display after querying a nested value, which makes you manually click every expand arrow to see the result, this makes it really hard to compare different rows. Does anyone know how to change it back?

[image: new nested column display]

Answer (score 0):

You can opt out by clicking disable editor tabs.
[image: here]

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion works. But I started using BigQuery in Dec 2021 so I am used to the new layout (they only changed how nested result is displayed recently) ->Disabling editor tabs introduces new changes to my usual interface lol. 

Also, they are going to disable the option to disable editor tabs in May 2022 so I guess we just have to live with the new changes :(