# Changing BigQuery's view of nested or array data

Tags: user-interface, google-bigquery

Within BigQuery you can have arrays, structs and other nested values for a single column. There seem to be two different views to display them, but how do you change the settings to determine how you want these values to be displayed?

In the first view you can show the nested values as text in a single row:
[image: bigquery image with nested values as single row]
*Image 1*

And with the 'toggle the entire column' button you can uncollapse the column and see each value individually:
[image: bigquery image with column an nested values displayed]
*Image 2*

There's the second view where you can have it organized in a way that everything is visible:
[image: bigquery view with columns and all nested values displayed neatly]
*Image 3*

How do you switch between these these two different views?

*Note:
The only possible related question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71567171/change-back-to-old-result-display-of-nested-values) but it recommends to Disable Editor Tabs, but they cannot be disabled (from 21 June 2022 onward). And I found that both these views are actually possible with Editor Tabs on, making that related question irrelevant now.*

Comment: but how you got all those screenshot? what it is that you did to switch between Image1,2 (which is what I think current way) and Image3 (which is what used to be a view at some point)?

Comment: Image 1 and 2 is from my computer, image 3 from a colleague. I can't get image 3 myself, my colleague can't get to image 1 and 2.

Comment: "And I found that both these views are actually possible with Editor Tabs on, making that related question irrelevant now." Could you post how to do this in a separate answer?

Comment: @ivospijker It's actually not "found out" in the sense that I found the answer, but that the screenshots were made on two separate accounts where both the Editor Tabs were enabed.

Comment: Hi @DoubleYou, I have provided a solution below. Consider accepting and upvoting it if you find the answer useful for the community.

Comment: It seems the ability to expand/collapse nested values has disappeared at the time of writing. I have posed a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74165194/what-happened-to-the-new-bigquery-ui-feature-to-toggle-display-of-nested-values asking where it might have gone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like image 3 was created using the old version of the UI. Which is still available when you click the `Disable editor tabs` button in the top right corner of the screen.

[image]

Google said they would disable the old version a while ago, but as long as people keep disabling the editor tabs and provide feedback on WHY they don't like the new UI they might postpone that a few more times.

Answer (score 0):

Disable editor tabs have been disabled by Google as of Jun 21, 2022 and will be completely disabled for all users soon. Without "editor tabs", I tried querying a nested table and was able to get output similar to Image 3.

[image]