# What happened to the new BigQuery UI feature to toggle display of nested values?

Tags: google-bigquery

At some point earlier this year BigQuery's UI gained a feature that I really liked, the ability to expand/collapse the display of nested values. Unfortunately this feature seems to have disappeared.

There's a SO post at [Changing BigQuery's view of nested or array data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72645952/changing-bigquerys-view-of-nested-or-array-data) that contains some images that show this UI really well and I'm hoping the poster of that message won't mind my including them here:

[image: collapsed nested values]

[image: expanded nested values]

As you can see the UI contained a little arrow button to toggle between the expanded and collapsed view.

I really liked this new feature and am disappointed that it no longer seems to be available. Does anyone know why it has gone and, more importantly, is it coming back?

Comment: Hi @jamie, There is no information available in [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes) regarding this change in BigQuery UI. If you want this feature in BigQuery, you can raise a feature request in [Issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

Comment: But clearly it was there, the screenshots prove it. I’d like to know why it was removed.